# Select list default multiple selection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

How can I set default values based on previous search?

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Filter.FossilTypes,
   new SelectList(Model.Filter.FossilsTypesOptions, "Name", "Name"),
   new { 
       @multiple = "multiple", 
       @placeholder = "Choose one...", 
       @class = "SlectBox" 
})
```

I tried this

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Filter.FossilTypes,
   new SelectList(Model.Filter.FossilsTypesOptions, "Name", "Name", Model.Filter.FossilTypesDefault),
   new { 
       @multiple = "multiple", 
       @placeholder = "Choose one...", 
       @class = "SlectBox" 
})
```

where switched `Model.Filter.FossilTypesDefault` type between `IEnumerable`, `Array` and `List`, but it had no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `ListBoxFor` helper instead of `DropDownListFor` for multiple selecftion values and pass selected `FossilTypesDefault` as first parameter of `@Html.ListBoxFor` helper like this:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.Filter.FossilTypesDefault, 
   new SelectList(Model.Filter.FossilsTypesOptions, "Name", "Name"),
   new { 
      @placeholder = "Choose one...", 
      @class = "SlectBox" 
})
```

`ListBoxFor` generate `multiple` attribute itself.

`FossilTypesDefault` should be `string[]` or `List<string>` in your case i gess.

Comment: That helped! Thanks!